# Was bedeutet "und verbleiben" am Ende einer Mail?

Tags: expression, letter

Ich habe zwei formale E-Mails von zwei Deutschen bekommen, die mit "und verbleiben" endeten (eine war auf Englisch geschrieben und sagte wörtlich "and remain with", was keinen Sinn gibt).

Was bedeutet eigentlich "und verbleiben" am Ende einer Mail? Ich habe diesen Ausdruck nie in anderen Sprachen gesehen.

Comment: Es gibt eine verwandte Frage bei ELL.SE: [the-correct-syntax-for-i-we-remain-at-the-end-of-the-letter](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47675/the-correct-syntax-for-i-we-remain-at-the-end-of-the-letter). Bei [dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/verbleiben) werden  _verbleiben_ und  _remain_ unter dem Stichwort "Phrasen/Collocations" als Briefschluß aufgelistet.

Comment: Was soll "kurz bekommen" bedeuten? Vor kurzem/kürzlich bekommen? Zwei kurze Mails bekommen?

Comment: @userunknown Vor kurzem/kürzlich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** Die Wendung ist eher gehoben. Man wollte ursprünglich damit ausdrücken, dass man sich nicht ändert (und implizierte damit, das sich die Beziehung zum Briefpartner nicht ändert).

Einen ähnlichen Briefschluss gibt es mit [*remain*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47675/the-correct-syntax-for-i-we-remain-at-the-end-of-the-letter) im Englischen.

---

Der Duden listet für [verbleiben](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verbleiben) unter

> *Bedeutungen, Beispiele und Wendungen*
>   [...]
>   **2.b. bleiben (1c)**
>          *Grammatik*
>           mit Gleichsetzungsnominativ
>           *Gebrauch*
>           gehoben
>           *Beispiele*
>     - er verblieb zeit seines Lebens ein Träumer
>             - **(in Grußformeln am Briefschluss) in Erwartung Ihrer Antwort verbleibe ich Ihr N. N.**
>             - **ich verbleibe mit freundlichen Grüßen Ihre N. N.**

Schlägt man die Bedeutung von [bleiben (1c)](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bleiben#b2-Bedeutung-1c) nach, steht dort:

> eine grundlegende Eigenschaft behalten

Ähnlich ist der Eintrag im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verbleiben) unter 1b):

> *gespreizt*
>   1. an einem Aufenthaltsort oder in einem Zustand bleiben
>   a) [...]
>   b) einen bestimmten Zustand beibehalten, nicht ändern
>   Beispiele:
>   - obwohl sie gewarnt worden war, verblieb sie bei ihrer Absicht
>   - dabei ist es vorläufig verblieben
>   - es verblieb bei der vagen Feststellung, er habe einen fieberhaften Infekt
>   - *veraltet* **mit den besten Grüßen verbleibe ich Ihr Freund K (= Briefschluss)**

Zur Herkunft weiß [Grimm](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/verbleiben) unter 4)

> *wie das einfache* bleiben *oft einen nominativ als prädicat zu sich nimmt (s. theil 2, 91), so auch* verbleiben *ein substantiv*
>   [...]
>   *hieraus entwickelt sich die beliebte kanzlei- und briefformel:* diene auch hinwiederum, wo ich kan und weisz und verbleibe euer .. Simplicius Simplicissimus. *Simpl. 1, 6, 4 Kurz*; wir verbleiben deroselben zu erweisung angenehmer dienste stete willige und geflissene. *Eisenacher archiv* 1700; verbleibe ihr ergebenster X